# Loading provider tiles over ssl using leaflet in R

Tags: r, ssl, https, leaflet

I have generated a map using the `leaflet` package in R. Everything works well and I can post the map to my website. My website uses SSL, however, and when the map is loaded I get mixed content notices because CartonDB.Positron is being loaded over http. Specifically, I get this message in the "Developer Tools - Console" in Chrome:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https:// mywebsite.com' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://b.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/12/1171/1566.png'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.

Is there a way to load provider tiles in Leaflet over SSL in R?

For example, can I specify in `addProviderTiles` to load from SSL? Right now I just have `addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron")`.

Answer (score 2):

The fix [@iH8](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2019281/ih8) suggested works. Here is my corresponding R code.

```
m <- leaflet() %>% addTiles('https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
    attribution = paste(
      '&copy; <a href="https://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
      '&copy; <a href="https://cartodb.com/attributions">CartoDB</a>'
    ))
```

Carto recommends the url [(1)](https://carto.com/location-data-services/basemaps/) :

`https://cartodb-basemaps-{s}.global.ssl.fastly.net/{style}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`

But just adding https:// to the normal url also works.

Answer (score 0):

They have hardcoded the http protocol into the URL so using the Carto provider isn't an option. I've raised an issue at their tracker: https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/issues/472

For the time being you could use a custom template:

```
addTiles(
    urlTemplate = "https://cartodb-basemaps-{s}.global.ssl.fastly.net/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
    attribution = '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>, | &copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attribution">Carto</a>', 
    options = tileOptions(minZoom = 0, maxZoom = 18)
)
```

Taken from: https://rpubs.com/walkerke/custom_tiles

Disclaimer, i am unable to test the function call above because i currently do not have RStudio installed on my system but as far as i know, it should work.

Comment: I agree this should work, but it isn't. The issue is the "s" in `urlTemplate = "https`. If you run the above code with the "s", the data points get plotted, but the background image is solid grey. If you remove the "s" and have "http", the map loads and becomes the background image. It seems calling "https" is the issue. Unfortunately, the `addTiles` option doesn't seem like a viable workaround.